# Remove sub-string from array elements and duplicate pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe:

```
number  |  matricule      
--------------------------------------------
1       |  ["AZ 1234", "1234", "00100"]                   
--------------------------------------------
23      |  ["1010", "12987"]                   
--------------------------------------------
56      |  ["AZ 98989", "22222", "98989"]                   
--------------------------------------------
```

In `matricule` array, I have duplicates values if I remove `AZ` String.
I would like to remove `"AZ"` string then remove duplicates values in `matricule`  array. Knowing that sometimes I have a space just after `AZ`, I should remove it also.

I did an udf:

```
def remove_AZ(A)
    for item in A:
        if item.startswith('AZ'):
            item.replace('AZ','')
udf_remove_AZ = F.udf(remove_AZ)
df = df.withColumn("AZ_2", udf_remove_AZ(df.matricule))
```

I got null in all `AZ_2` column.

How can I remove the AZ from the each value in `matricule` array then removing the duplicates inside ?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+, you can use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) + [`array_distinct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_distinct) function like this:

```
t = "transform(matricule, x -> trim(regexp_replace(x, '^AZ', '')))"
df.withColumn("matricule", array_distinct(expr(t))).show(truncate=False) 

#+------+--------------+
#|number|matricule     |
#+------+--------------+
#|1     |[1234, 00100] |
#|23    |[1010, 12987] |
#|56    |[98989, 22222]|
#+------+--------------+
```

For each element of the array, using `transform`, we remove `AZ` characters from the beginning of the string using [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_replace) and [`trim`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#trim) the leading and trailing spaces if there are.

Answer (score 4):

Can you write your udf as:

```
def remove_az(array):
    array = [w.replace('AZ', '').strip() for w in array]
    return array

remove_az_udf = F.udf(remove_az)

df = df.withColumn("AZ_2", remove_az_udf(df.matricule))
```